# asp.net mvc update multiple records

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

is it possible to have a view for editing multiple records, in the same way that the index.cshtml view loops through records to display them (as below)?

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tvid)
    </td>
```

So for each row above, it would relate to a different row in the database.

Does anyone know of any examples showing how this may be achieved?

Thanks for any pointers,

Mark

**UPDATE**

Model:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

namespace MvcObjectives.Models
{
public class objectives
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int tvid { get; set; }
    public string tlnt { get; set; }
    public DateTime month { get; set; }

    public string objective  { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }
    public int possscore { get; set; }
    public string comments { get; set; }
 }
```

}

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(objectives objectives)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(objectives).State = EntityState.Modified;
            foreach (objective Objective in objectives.objective)

            { }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(objectives);
    }
```

I'm stick with the controller, if anyone can offer any assistance?

Thanks again,

Mark

**2nd Update**

The GET Controller to send the records to the view is:

```
        // GET: /Objective/Edit/
        public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            return View(db.objectives.ToList());
        }
```

The POST controller (where the values are posted back from the view) is:

```
        // POST: /Objective/Edit/
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(List<objectives> objectives)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
         // the next part is where I am stuck - how to loop through the returned objectives, and update the records in the database
                db.Entry(objectives).State = EntityState.Modified;
                foreach (objectives obj in objectives)
                {
                    var tempObj = (from objv in db.objectives
                                   where objv.ID==obj.ID
                                   select objv).First();
              }

              //  to do - how to save the updates sent back????

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(objectives);
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an **Editor template**

Assuming your ViewModel/Model looks like this

```
public class UserViewModel 
{
  public int UserId { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}   
  public IEnumerable<Address> Addresses { set;get;}

  public UserViewModel()
  {
     if(this.Addresses==null)
         this.Addresses=new List<Address>();
  }
}
public class Address
{
  public int AddressID { set;get;}
  public string AddressLine1 { set;get;}
}
```

Now create an editor template called `addresses.cshtml` with below content.

```
@model YourNameSpace.Address
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AddressLine1)
```

In your main view, you can call this like

```
@model UserViewModel 
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  //other elements
 @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Addresses)
 <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Now you will get the data in your HttpPost Ation method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(UserViewModel model)
{  
   foreach (Address address in model.Addresses)
   {
      //now check for address.AddressLine here
   } 
}
```

**EDIT**  : Based on the user's comment and updation on the question.

(***Request to the OP*** : *Next time when you post a question, include all the relevant details to the question in the first time itself*.)

Create a ViewModel to wrap your List of Objective class.

```
public class ObjectivesEdit
{
    public IEnumerable<Objective> Objectives { set; get; }
    public ObjectivesEdit()
    {
        if (Objectives == null)
            Objectives = new List<Objective>();
    }
}
```

And in your GET Action method send this Wrapper View model to the View with values filled

```
  public ActionResult Edit()
  {
     ObjectivesEdit objEdit = new ObjectivesEdit();
     List<Objective> objList = new List<Objective>();
       // you can replace this manual filling with data from database
     objList.Add(new Objective { ID = 1, score = 65 });
     objList.Add(new Objective { ID = 2, score = 43 });
     objList.Add(new Objective { ID = 3, score = 78 });
     objEdit.Objectives = objList;
     return View(objEdit);
  }
```

Your Editor template should look like this. It should be named `objective.cshtml`

```
@model EditorTemplateDemo.Models.Objective           
<p>
Score for @Model.ID is  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.score)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)
</p>
```

And your main View

```
@model EditorTemplateDemo.Models.ObjectivesEdit
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Objectives)
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />    
}
```

And finally your HTTPPOST action method will look like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ObjectivesEdit model)
    {
        if (model.Objectives != null)
        {
            // Put a break point here and you will see the posted data
            foreach (var item in model.Objectives)
            {
                 context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            //Save and redirect  
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");     
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

This should work. Tested.

To avoid further questions, I am sharing a working sample of the above code [here](http://sdrv.ms/K9NKs0). Please use visual studio breakpoints int he code to see what value is being posted.

Comment: Hi - I'm struggling with the controller - would you be able to help?  My model is:    public class objectives
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int tvid { get; set; }
        public string tlnt { get; set; }
        public DateTime month { get; set; }
        
        public string objective  { get; set; }
        public int score { get; set; }
        public int possscore { get; set; }
        public string comments { get; set; }
     }

Comment: My Controller, where I'm stuck is:  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(objectives objectives)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(objectives).State = EntityState.Modified;
                foreach (objective Objective in objectives.objective)

                { }

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(objectives);
        }

Comment: where is multiple items coming here ?

Comment: I do not see an collection in your model

Comment: Hi - I added the code above to my original post.  Using Fiddler, I can see the post back to the server when I click update, and it is passing back (in the post) the updates to the multiple objectives listed - I just can't figure out how to loop through the returned object, to save each one to the database (I'm not sure what a collection is, or if it's required, given the data is being posted back)??  Thank you again, Mark

Comment: @MarkTait: Oh. Can you tell me where you want the multiple items ? Which property is that ?

Comment: Hi @Shyju - I would like the multiple items in the posted data, to be saved back to the database - the start of my code (on the ActionResult (Edit) controller is:  foreach (objectives obj in objectives)
                {
                    var tempObj = (from objv in db.objectives
                                   where objv.ID==obj.ID
                                   select objv).First();
                   Once I've found the current item in the database, I'm not sure how to update it with the posted results?  Thank you.

Comment: @MarkTait : Can you tell me which property in your model has multiple instances ? i do not see anything there ? How does your GET action looks like ? That will help me to understand better. pls post in the question

Comment: I have added to the original post again... Can I thank you for taking any time to try and assist - I really do appreciate it.

Comment: See the updated answer. I hope it will help people who are curious about how to update the entry in loop.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a model called Person.. and you want to edit a bunch of persons in a View and post them to an action.

```
public ViewResult Edit()
{
    return View(list of persons to edit);
}

public ViewResult Edit(List<Person> persons)
{
    // save to db?
}
```

Now to create a view that displays say multiple persons to edit.

Edit.cshtml

```
@model List<Person>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
   <h4>Person Number: @i</h4>
   @:First Name: @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].FirstName)
   @:Last Name: @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].LastName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in  [EditorTemplates](http://dineshkumara.blogspot.com/2011/06/mvc-3-razor-editor-template.html)